# Why is the verb singular in "What's in the bags?"

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

In a picture book, a boy carried two bags full of stuff he bought from a garage sale.  His mum asked,

> "What's in the bags?"

My question is why did they use "What's" instead of "What are"?  I think since it is apparent that there are quite a few items in the bag, "What are" should be the more appropriate expression.

I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Similarly, the name of the show is *Who **Wants** to Be a Millionaire?* rather than *Want*, even though presumably everyone would want to be a millionaire. As far as I know, singular is the default choice in this kind of question.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I was about to call "what is" a _free relative clause_ here, and that might be another justification for permitting the singular...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The contraction **What's** in your example expands to **What is.**

*CGEL* (pages 505-6:) tells us in Section 19 under **Interrogatives**:

> In general, the interrogative pronouns *who* and *what* take the default value of singular.

Later in the same section, it also tells us:

> The default singular values for *who* and *what* can, however, be overridden when there is a presupposition that the answer is plural:    (examples follow)

If there is an expectation or prior knowledge that the pronoun refers to a plural subject, the default singular value may not be expected. In your question (as edited) there are multiple items in the bags. It may therefore be proper to use the plural form of the verb in:

> What are in the bags?

However, there is an important distinction between *proper* or *grammatically justifiable* and *idiomatic.* In common speech and usage, the question would very seldom be posed in that way by a native English speaker. In particular, the contraction **What's** is used in numerous contexts in which a plural verb might be "correct," but in which the construction *What are* would elicit puzzlement from the listener. For example:

> What are going on?
>   What are new with you?
>   What are on television tonight?

When *what* is used as an *interrogative pronoun* and subject, it usually takes the singular form of a verb. To take the plural form, your example question could be reformulated so that *what* functions instead as an *interrogative adjective:*

> What items are in the bags?

(A detailed answer to this and related questions can be found under the question [*Which is the correct question (“Who has” vs “Who have”)?*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/31139/37009))

> ---
>
> <sup>Addendum: A harmless drudge asserts that *what* in the present construction may represent what he calls a "special singular sense" of the pronoun. It obtains only when the preposition following *what's* is *in,* and when the object of *in* is a noun or NP that describes a container. He reasons: *There is an elision in the construction "What's in the sth" when sth is a container; the elided words are **each thing.*** The OP's sentence, in his reasoning, therefore parses correctly as *What is (each thing) in the bag?*</sup>

Comment: "***What are*** *the names of the Founding Fathers?*" I must use a plural verb here,  mustn't I?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The subject is _names._ The declarative form is _The names of the Founding Fathers are what._ Confusing, without a doubt. That's why I link to the answer above.

Comment: That's great. What about "what are in the galaxies?" I am saying that since I read the post that you mentioned above. It says the default singular-state of "what" can be overwrite when we can guess the answer will be in plural form.

Comment: I'm not sure that *what* is the subject in the OP's sentence. In the question: "**What happens next?**". *what* is the subject. I think "the bags" is the subject, the sentence could also be: "What are in the bags?" What's wrong with that question? :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's idiomatic to "require" that the interrogative _what_ is treated as singular. The declarative forms of the OP's sentence are: _In the bags is what_ and the sentence itself without the question mark: _What is in the bags._ If "what" is not the subject, "what is?" (Goodness, this is fun!)

Comment: @Cardinal It's idiomatic to treat a question like "What are in the galaxies?" as ungrammatical, but as that answer says, there can be exceptions due to context. In the OP's case, though, it's hard to see one.

Comment: "When what is used as an interrogative pronoun and subject, it can only take the singular form of a verb." -- Some counterexamples: *What are there? What are the matters?* (It's relatively easy to find lengthier and more realistic examples along the same lines in Google Books, BTW.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I'll edit that to make it less commanding. :) But it is idiomatic to treat the interrogative _what_ as a singular, and I'm not making that up!

Comment: I agree that it's idiomatic (or in my own words, "the default choice"), but to say that *it can only take the singular form* is probably too restrictive. :-)