# it is you who has vs. it is you who have

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, subject-verb-agreement, auxiliary-verbs

There is already a similar question here, but it is about forming questions:
[Which is the correct question ("Who has" vs "Who have")?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/which-is-the-correct-question-who-has-vs-who-have)

When combining *who* with *you* in a statement, which is correct and why?

> It is you who has chosen.
>
> It is you who have chosen.

*who* is third-person singular, so it takes *has*.
*you* is second-person, so it takes *have*.

Does the verb *to have* conjugate with *you* or *who* in this sentence? Which one is correct, or can it vary?

Comment: @Octopus But you don't say _You has apples_ for one person and _You have apples_ for more than one person. You say _You **have** apples_ for both.

Comment: Yes, my comment was completely inaccurate. Deleting :(

Answer (score 3):

It's you who has chosen.

It's you who have chosen.

The former isn't grammatical whereas the latter is OK.

It's a cleft sentence divided into two clauses. The first clause "it's you" is a focussed clause. The verb in the second clause agrees with the subject in the first clause; if the subject is in the singular or plural, the verb in the other clause is used accordingly. But, as the pronoun you, whether in the singular or plural,  always takes a plural verb, you must use have, not has, in the sentence presented.

[Cambridge Dictionary online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/cleft-sentences-it-was-in-june-we-got-married)

Comment: It would be really helpful to visitors if you could include a good reference and link (in your answer), that explains what "cleft sentences" are in more detail.

Comment: @Mari-LouA,  I always appreciate your valuable comments. I'll give a reference.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-order-and-focus/cleft-sentences-it-was-in-june-we-got-married

Comment: I asked, in brackets, *in the answer*. I can find references for myself, but good answers should be self contained.

Comment: @Mari-LouA,  you are right.

Comment: I agree that _It’s the parents who **were** protesting most_ is definitely correct. It gets trickier when you drop a pronoun in. _It's I who **am** the best!_

Answer (score -1):

I think it depends on the number of people you're talking about. If it is just one person, then use *has*. If it is more than one person, use *have*. It all really comes down to this simple rule.

Example #1:

> It is **you who has** broken the law here! Not me!

Example #2:

> It is **you guys who have** broken the law here!. Not me!

Comment: From what I learnt in school, subject pronoun=antecedent, so if *You* agrees with *have*, *who* must do so.

Comment: Right. But the antecedent of "has" and "have" here must  be "who". And that "who" depends on "you". And that "you" depends on how many people you've got in mind. For the singular you, it should be one person and for the plural you, it should be a bunch of people. Why is this so difficult to grasp?

Comment: That makes sense, but I'm afraid, because singular and plural *you* takes the same verb

Comment: First of all, "you" is not a subject pronoun in this case, it's an object one. You're conflating two different ideas here.

Comment: "I gave the books to you" / "I gave you the books" = "You were given the books" NOT "You was given..." The pronoun *you* could be referring to a single person or to a group" but the verb that follows is always plural (unless you happen to speak [AAVE](http://web.stanford.edu/~zwicky/aave-is-not-se-with-mistakes.pdf)). P.S by adding "guys" you're changing the OP's example, *You guys have..* is of course grammatical, try saying *You guys has...* PPS (for visitors) Not my DV